# What does Paul Avery tell the coffee guy after the coffee guy calls him a "drunken reprobate"?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, zodiac

In the movie "Zodiac" from 2007, what does Paul Avery tell the coffee guy at approximately 43:54 into the movie right after the coffee guy calls him a "drunken reprobate"?

I've searched multiple sites with transcripts and none of them have the line. It just cuts right to "We interrupt our regular programming to bring you this special news bulletin."

Comment: Have you tried reading a subtitle SRT file? It opens up in any text editor. Also, 2007 or 2009?

Comment: ["Finish up, buddy, and put it in the sink."](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=Zodiac&title_id=M238066772&q=Good+morning%2C+Melvin.+-+Good+morning%2C+Jim.&search_sort=Popularity&genre=-1&type=All)?

Comment: Its in Italian if that helps I think, but I don't speak it well enough. Meta sculio gratis it sounds like.

Comment: The last part is definitely grazie (thanks). First part is... minuscolo (small)? Pronounced really badly? Maybe regarding the cup?

Comment: There's nothing in the script that helps; http://www.screenplaydb.com/film/scripts/Zodiac.PDF

Comment: @Richard I doubt it would be there. Just seems like something RDJ improvised.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! I think I'm gonna go with Walt's answer. That makes sense. That cup is pretty small. It's hard to make out a sudden language switch in the middle of a movie that was filmed in a different one.

Comment: I'm italian but i really can't understand what RDJ is mumbling ... It seems like he'saying something like ["**minuscolo**"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcKePNLTaYU) as Walt pointed out. And I guess it would make sense 'cos the name of the guy is [**Shorty**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0140108/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t27), but in Italy we would say "Corto" or "Tappo" (if teasing about height) while "minuscolo" means "tiny" or even ["**lower case**"](http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/minuscolo). I'm trying to find the italian dubbed version to see how it has been translated ;)

Comment: *"Shorty"* Best theory so far (I forgot that was the character's name). It's possible the 2nd word is not even Italian and he's using **2** languages (or even just making up some 'foreign' sounding version of minuscule), but this makes the most sense.

Comment: I've found the italian dubbed version of the bit and Robert Downey Jr. says: *"por supuesto, gracias"* which translated in english should be something along the lines of *"of course, thank you"*. I've been trying to think about a different italian word that sounds like "minuscolo" and means something like "of course", but none comes to mind. It is also possible that the italian translation in spanish has nothing to do with the original meaning and was only chosen to match Robert Downey Jr.'s lips movements.

Comment: @Pesetas74 "Thanks, Shorty" still seems like the safest bet. Perhaps put this up, so we can put this thing to bed? ;)

Answer (score 5):

As per my comments above, I've tried to listen carefully many times to what Robert Downey Jr. is mumbling in *italian* in the following scene (at approximately 43:42 as suggested by the OP):

and I agree with the preceding comments that he probably says *"minuscolo grazie"*.

My best guess is that the first italian word, "minuscolo", might be referred to the character's name [**Shorty**](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0007510/bio), played by the actor **[James Carraway](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0140108/)**, although "[**minuscolo**](http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/minuscolo)" is not a very accurate translation of the original english word. In italian, when teasing someone about his height, we would say "Corto" or "Tappo" while "[**minuscolo**](http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/minuscolo)" actually means "tiny" or even "lower case".

But the *poor* choice of words might also be due to the fact that, as suggested by Walt in his comment, Robert Downey Jr. might have just improvised the bit. This is also corroborated by the fact that there seems to be no trace of the *dialogue* in the [script](http://www.screenplaydb.com/film/scripts/Zodiac.PDF).

The second italian word, "grazie", is much easier to understand and so the corresponding english translation of *"minuscolo grazie"* would be *"Thanks Shorty"*.

Also, the fact that the sequence of the two words is reversed by Robert Downey Jr. (as in english we would say *"grazie minuscolo"* and not the opposite), doesn't help much.

I've also listened to the italian dubbed version of the bit, in the hope of better understanding the original meaning, but it didn't help much, because the phrase has been translated in spanish, and I'm almost positive (I'm Italian and don't know much of spanish) that he says *"por supuesto, gracias"*, which translated in english should mean something along the lines of *"of course/sure, thank you"*.